# Assigning an ID to a td within a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have converted an xml file into a HTML table. The function I have used is here:

```
document.write("<table><tr><td>ALPHA</td><td>BRAVO</td><td>CHARLIE</td><td>DELTA</td><td>
ECHO</td><td>FOXTROT</td><td>GOLF</td><td>HOTEL</td></tr>");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("List");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(i) //populates the ALPHA column
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("BRAVOITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>")
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CHARLIEITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DELTAITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td></td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("FOXTROTITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
}
 document.write("</table>")
```

The table presents exactly what I want  and I plan to add the ECHOITEMS, GOLFITEMS and HOTELITEMS later.

My issue is, in order to progress any further, I need to assign IDs to each td above, so I can pull data from the table. I am able to assign an ID to a normal HTML td but I am struggling to so within the JavaScript code above. I need to add an ID to each td consisting of a short string followed by the i number. For example, using the first few lines of code above:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("List");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
document.write("<tr id='tdalpha'+ i><td>");
document.write(i)
document.write("</td><td id='tdbravo' + i>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("BRAVOITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

etc. Obviously the syntax isn't correct as when I try:

```
var test = document.getElementById('tdalpha24')
document.write(test)
```

I get an error message.

Any suggestions as to how to do this properly?!

Comment: Why use `document.write()`? Also, would you mind sharing what the error was?

Comment: Use `id=`, not `index=`.

Comment: I'm using document.write as this is what was suggested by http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp. I meant id, rather than index, changed above. I don't get an error message, but I get a null value. document.write(test) returns 'null'. How do I start a new line in these comments?

Comment: Don't use document.write. Never-ever. You simply don't need it, it's used in very specific cases. And this tutorial you referenced in not very good quality.

Answer (score 2):

you can do so like this -

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
document.write('<tr id="tdalpha'+i'"><td>');
document.write(i)
document.write('</td><td id="tdbravo'+i+'">');
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("BRAVOITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

As almost everybody before me noticed: "do not use document.write". In most cases it's considered bad technique.
And if you still want to use it, make one big string and use document.write only one time. It will increase perfomance. Just like this:

```
var str = '<table><tr><td>ALPHA</td><td>BRAVO</td><td>CHARLIE</td><td>DELTA</td><td>ECHO</td><td>FOXTROT</td><td>GOLF</td><td>HOTEL</td></tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    str += '<tr id="tdalpha'+i'"><td>';
    str += i;
    str += '</td><td id="tdbravo'+i+'">';
    str += x[i].getElementsByTagName("BRAVOITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    str += '</td><td>';
    str += x[i].getElementsByTagName("CHARLIEITEMS")   [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    str += '</td><td>';
    str += x[i].getElementsByTagName("DELTAITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    str += '</td><td></td><td>';
    str += x[i].getElementsByTagName("FOXTROTITEMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    str += "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
}
str += '</table>';
document.write(str);
```

PS and your 'i' variable looks global to me.

Comment: Thanks Lends, that works. Can I ask what you suggest instead of document.write? Forgive my lack of knowledge! CK

Comment: I do not really know how and where you use this code. But it's ok to use document.write and document.writeln before DOM is created, otherwise it will rewrite whole document. And these two methods can put broken hypertext in your document. 

If you use this code when DOM is created, just add an element to your document and use: element.innerHTML = str. innerHTML is slower than document.write but it will not erase whole document and browser will try to make your HTML valid.